# Lost mod_ssl on debian, how to get it back?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-ssl

I lost my mod_ssl on my debian machine. How can I get it back.

I accidently removed it from mods_available instead of mods_enable, and as it was a symlink I lost the file. Is it possible to get this back without ruining the configurations of apache?

Is there any libapache2-mod I can reinstall, in case please include how I remove + reinstall it.

Thanks.

Comment: Restore a backup or a part from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

   SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
   SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
   SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
   SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512

   AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
   AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

   SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

   #SSLSessionCache         dbm:/var/run/apache2/ssl_scache
   SSLSessionCache        shmcb:/var/run/apache2/ssl_scache(512000)
   SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

   SSLMutex  file:/var/run/apache2/ssl_mutex
   SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!ADH
   #SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

</IfModule>
```

This should be Debian 6.0 like ssl.conf in /etc/apache2/mods-available

```
 LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

This should be Debian 6.0 like ssl.load in /etc/apache2/mods-available